# Highcharts - tooltip zindex relative to series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to render my tooltip behind the series in a solid gauge. I have tried changing the z-index and opacity in the style parameter, but this does not seem to change anything.

tooltip.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

const tooltip = (props) => {
    let container = `#score-visual-${props.equation.eqId}`;
    return {
        useHTML: true,
        animation: false,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius:   40,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        shadow:false,
        style:{
            fontSize: '14px'
    },
        formatter: function () {
            return `<table>
                <tr><td style="font-size:1.6em; color:${this.point.color}; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">
                ${this.y}${this.point.unit}
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td style="text-align: center"">
                ${this.series.name}
                </td></tr>

            </table>`
        },
        positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
            return {
                x: ($(container).width() - labelWidth) / 2,
                y: ($(container).height() - labelHeight) / 2 + 35
            };
        }
    }
};

export default tooltip;
```

Please see the full code here:
https://github.com/ncernek/react-highcharts-error

--

**EDIT**

The problem (note that tooltip background overlaps the series):
[image]

The intended solution (note that tooltip does not overlap the series):
[image]

Comment: Could you post an image of what your expected outcome should be? There may be an alternative way of accomplishing what you want besides a tooltip, which is meant to be visible, above the data lines.

Comment: Why you cannot disable the tooltip background? Set the [backgroundColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.backgroundColor) as 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'

Comment: That is a good thought. I forgot to mention that, when no tooltip is displayed, there is a static number at the center of the ring. This acts as the default piece of info. The tooltip needs to be able to cover it up.